# How to handle multiple dropdown filters on a page in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

So here is the scenario:

There are 4 dropdown filters(namely a,b,c,d)on a webpage.
In case the value received by the event triggered is "-1" or "undefined" , the complete data received from the API needs to be displayed while in other cases we need to match and display the matching entries.

The issue is that at any point there can any number of filters applied and for the same reason we have to handle every possible permutation. A normal approach is becoming really cumbersome and has lots of if else scenarios.

Is there is simpler approach to handling such case ?

Thanks.

Comment: what i understand from your question is that, you want to apply the options that are selected from dropdown as filters on data that is provided by API... Is that right?

Comment: @Krishna- Yes Sir and the data displayed should be matching the applied filter/s

Comment: Is it your own API or something from a 3rd party?

Comment: Instead of calling api again you can store the full data in variable and apply pipe filter in angular and pass the selected values as params to the pipe and your logic to filter data goes in pipe

Comment: @abney317 - Our own API.

Comment: @Krishna - Sure let me try this.

Comment: @Krishna - Hi Krishna.But can the pipe filter be applied on the array of objects ?

Comment: @Mukul_Vashistha - Hi, Little busy with something else, please check this link (https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes) and try.